# return false has to stop execution in java script

Tags: c#, javascript, return

i was comparing from date and to date in java script if the value is false i am returning false but the program is executing.

my java script code

```
function Noofdays() {

        var total= document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_Txtabc');
            var days = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ddldays');

            if (total= days) {
                alert("same");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("not same");
                return false;
            }   
        }
```

i was calling this function from c# code in save button,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "FromDateSample", "Noofdays();", true);
```

and i had a on client click event in save button.

Comment: = is assignment, == or === is comparison

Answer (score 1):

The condition of your if-statement is assigning the value of `days` to `total`. To compare the two values, you need to use a comparison operator (`==` or `===`).

Comment: i did it but my programe still executes when the condition is false

Comment: i had given return false but it was not working,how can i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

1. = is assignment, == or === is comparison
2. You need to tack a .value on to your fields
3. You may want to convert to numbers

   ```
   var total= +document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_Txtabc').value;
   var days = +document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_ddldays').value;
   if (total==days) {
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use **return** before function calling.

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "FromDateSample", "**return** Noofdays();", true);

**Button:**

> <asp:Button ... OnClientClick="**return** Noofdays();">